# How to get number of lines resulted by join in Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, join

Consider these two Dataframes:

```
+---+
|id |
+---+
|1  |
|2  |
|3  |
+---+


+---+-----+
|idz|word |
+---+-----+
|1  |bat  |
|1  |mouse|
|2  |horse|
+---+-----+
```

I am doing a `Left join on ID=IDZ`:

```
val r = df1.join(df2, (df1("id") === df2("idz")), "left_outer").
      withColumn("ID_EMPLOYE_VENDEUR", when(col("word") =!= ("null"), col("word")).otherwise(null)).drop("word")

r.show(false)

+---+----+------------------+
|id |idz |ID_EMPLOYE_VENDEUR|
+---+----+------------------+
|1  |1   |mouse             |
|1  |1   |bat               |
|2  |2   |horse             |
|3  |null|null              |
+---+----+------------------+
```

But what if I only want to keep the lines whose ID only have one equal IDZ? If not, I would Like to have null in ID_EMPLOYE_VENDEUR. Desired output is:

```
+---+----+------------------+
|id |idz |ID_EMPLOYE_VENDEUR|
+---+----+------------------+
|1  |1   |null              | --Because the Join resulted two different lines
|2  |2   |horse             |
|3  |null|null              |
+---+----+------------------+
```

I should precise that I am working on a large DF. The solution should be not very expensive in time.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you mentioned data your data is too large, so `groupBy` is not good option to group data and join  [Windows over function](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-windows.html)  as below :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("idz")

val newDF = df1.withColumn("count", count("idz").over(windowSpec)).dropDuplicates("idz").withColumn("word", when(col("count") >=2 , lit(null)).otherwise(col("word"))).drop("count")

val r = df1.join(newDF, (df1("id") === newDF("idz")), "left_outer").withColumn("ID_EMPLOYE_VENDEUR", when(col("word") =!= ("null"), col("word")).otherwise(null)).drop("word") 
 r show 
+---+----+------------------+
| id| idz|ID_EMPLOYE_VENDEUR|
+---+----+------------------+
|  1|   1|              null|
|  3|null|              null|
|  2|   2|             horse|
+---+----+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve easily the information that more than two `df2`'s `idz` matched a single `df1`'s `id` with a groupBy and a join.

```scala
r.join(
    r.groupBy("id").count().as("g"),
    $"g.id" === r("id")
  )
  .withColumn(
    "ID_EMPLOYE_VENDEUR",
    expr("if(count != 1, null, ID_EMPLOYE_VENDEUR)")
  )
  .drop($"g.id").drop("count")
  .distinct()
  .show()
```

*Note:* Both the groupBy and the join **do not trigger any additional exchange step** (shuffle around network) because the dataframe `r` is already partitioned on `id` (because it is the result of a join on `id`).